# Edit Word Documents on GCP Bucket Using Google Docs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mean-stack, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have built a MEAN stack web application and it has a feature where the users can upload a word document to it. The uploaded documents are stored in GCP a Bucket and I have access to download the files using their URLs. Is there a way I can edit those documents using Google Docs?

Comment: Cloud  Storage only provided the storage service, depends on the frequency you intend to edit the word file. You can choose to use serverless productions like Cloud Function, which fir for low-frequency request or App engine standard can persist serve for the edit request with reasonable cozy. Let me know your exact requirement include the runtime you prefer, I will provide more details and sample codes for you to refer to.

Comment: There are two types of users; admin and regular user and there are templates under each client’s name. Means, there folders with client name and each folder contains word document templates. The admin user should be able to create templates and as well as edit the templates.

Comment: Then the regular user should be able to pick one of the templates and start working on it. When the regular user works on it, the template should be opened using Google Docs.

Comment: Also, when the regular user picks a template, the system should actually make a copy of that template and allow the user to edit the copy, not the actual template. Please let me know any other way of communication if you do not understand this. I really want to get this done within this week. Really appreciate it.

Comment: how many users do you estimate at this stage to use this service? the location of the uses will be close to each other or the world widely?

Comment: Your requirement sounds like a scenario that long-distance education on how the lecturer assigns homework sheets to students. Actually I do not think you need to develop this service, which Google Drive, Google Docs can meet your requirement. Do you consider that ? if the user and template manager are unknow.. it may need a couple of simple Cloud Function and a tiny Cloud SQL service plus  Google Drive, Google Docs API can acheive that.

Comment: At the moment, it is only 30 users max. The users are both globally and as well as sitting next to each other. I want the users and the template managers to be known users due to some security and confidentiality requirements. Also, the documents cannot be stored in Google Drive since it does not have server storages in Australia, however, GCP Storage does.